# The compiler does not swear at methods from es6 if webpack is installed

Tags: typescript, webpack

file index.ts

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
const result = array.flat()
console.log(result)
```

I install the package in package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
}
```

file tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

I run the command `tsc --build`. The compiler throws an error

```
target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2019' or later.

2 const result = a.flat()
                   ~~~~
Found 1 error.
```

But if you add the webpack package to package.json. And run the `tsc --build` command. The project will build successfully. Why?

```
"devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2"
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. Testing with node v14 and node v16